# ffmpeg: How do I re-encode a video to H.264 video and AAC audio?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, aac

I'm trying to re-encode a video produced with "TechSmith Screen Capture Codec" in WinUAE to use H.264 video and AAC audio, with the latest "ffmpeg" (20200510-fc99a24) 64-bit, but when I use the following line with ffmpeg, it seems to encode OK, but results in a video file that doesn't play on anything:

```
"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i output.avi -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -acodec mp3 -b:a 160k done.mkv
```

I realise the audio is MP3, but I don't know how to use AAC in ffmpeg.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `-c:a aac`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -vf format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- `input.avi` is the input file.
- `-c:v libx264` selects the video encoder *libx264*, which is a H.264 encoder.
- `-preset slow` selects the *slow* x264 encoding preset. Default preset is *medium*. Use the slowest preset that you have patience for.
- `-crf 20` selects a CRF value of 20 which will result in a high quality output. Default value is 23. A lower value is a higher quality. Use the highest value that gives an acceptable quality.
- `-c:a aac` selects the audio encoder *aac*, which is the built-in FFmpeg AAC encoder.
- `-b:a 160k` encodes the audio with a bitrate of 160k.
- `-vf format=yuv420p` chooses YUV 4:2:0 chroma-subsampling which is recommended for H.264 compatibility.
- `-movflags +faststart` is an option for MP4 output that move some data to the beginning of the file after encoding is finished. This allows the video to begin playing faster if it is watched via progressive download playback.
- `output.mp4` is the output file.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) and [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -b:v 2600k -pass 2 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

from the [official ffmpeg documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Comment: Why suggest two-pass?